# Google Analytics Goal submission after Gravity Form payment

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, gravity-forms-plugin

For one of my sites I am using a Gravity Form plugin in combination with a Dutch payment gateway to receive new subscriptions. I would like to add a goal to my Google Analytics account with the amount of subscriptions per day. After a successful subscription a hidden "Thank you" page is loaded.

I've already various things:

1. Using the "Gravity Forms Google Analytics Event Tracking" plug-in, however the plug-in posts to Google Analytics when connecting to the payment gateway. Because of this all payments that are canceled or not accepted are also showing up in Google Analytics.
2. I have tried to use the Google Analytics goal page. Using this way we monitor if the user loads the successful payment page. However, when the page is refreshed Google Analytics will count it as two payments.

Has someone have an idea how to solve this problem in a reliable way?